# Change html5 class based on variable change in Angular 6?

Tags: angular

How can I add / remove a class in `html` element, based on the value assigned in a variable in the model. For example, I have a `value` variable inside of my Angular component:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    value: number = 6;
    ...
}
```

Now, based on the value (which is updated quite often via an event listener), I want to add / remove a class in the `html` element when the condition is true:

```
<div [ngClass]="value >= 3 ? 'bordered-section' : ''"></div>

<div [ngClass]="value >= 6 ? 'bordered-section' : ''"></div>
```

I think I managed to make this work on initialization, but when the variable changes again, the classes are not removed. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div [ngClass]="{'bordered-section' : value >= 3 }"></div>

<div [ngClass]="{'bordered-section' : value >= 6 }"></div>
```

Should work by this way, `ngClass` should get an Object with classes names

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
<div [ngClass]="{'bordered-section1' : value == 3 , 'bordered-section2' :value > 5 }"></div>
```

also this way possible

```
<div [ngClass]="{'bordered-section' : value >= 3 || value <=6 }"></div>
```

you can add or remove class based on boolean expression with ngClass directive